# Shift bits of a float in MIPS without MTC1

Tags: floating-point, mips

I'm currently working on a school assignment that requires me to find the biased exponent of a single precision float without using the `mtc1` command that comes with MIPS. I am wondering how it would be possible to use `sll` or `srl` on the inputted result

The below code is what I am trying to achieve

```
li    $v0, 6
sll   $a2, $f0, 1 // Wrong type error here
srl   $a2, $a2, 24
```

How would I be able to do something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can't mix FPR and GPR in the same instruction like that, except in MFC* and MTC*

If data is currently on memory, you can load it directly to a GPR with `lw`. If it's on an FPR then you need to store to memory and load from memory to GPR

```
swc1  $f0, 0($a3)  # store from FPR to memory
lw    $t1, 0($a3)  # load from memory to GPR
sll   $a2, $t1, 1  # shift like normal
srl   $a2, $a2, 24
```